# Dynamic android form from XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-custom-view

I want to generate a form into my activity_main.xml ScrollView. XML is loaded and parsed correctly but when I'm trying to addView(LinearLayout) then it throws exception e. My application gets url of a XML file via push notification and then parses it. According to XML it then should generate a form and display it to the user. I used this as an example: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-andddyntut/#l1

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
Controller aController;
public ScrollView sv;
Button execute;

// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

public static String name;
public static String email;

final Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);

...
}

// Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen 
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
        new DoInBackground(getApplicationContext(), sv).execute(newMessage);

        // Releasing wake lock
        aController.releaseWakeLock();

    }
};
```

and here is my async class:

```
public class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

Context mContext;
ScrollView mSv;

String tag = "DynamicFormXML";
XmlGuiForm theForm;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Handler progressHandler;

public DoInBackground(Context context, ScrollView sv) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSv = sv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    if (GetFormData(params[0])) {
        DisplayForm();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(tag,"Couldn't parse the Form.");
        AlertDialog.Builder bd = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        AlertDialog ad = bd.create();
        ad.setTitle("Error");
        ad.setMessage("Could not parse the Form data");
        ad.show();

    }
    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute() {

}

private boolean DisplayForm()
{

    try
    {           
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        mSv.addView(ll); //Here it fails
        ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
...
    } catch (Exception e) { // Goes to here
        Log.e(tag,"Error Displaying Form");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the context of the main activity and also the empty Scrollview in main activity are forwarded correctly (they are not null) but i'm not 100% sure. Any help/hints are appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not touch the GUI from a background thread (e.g. the one running the `doInBackground` method).

In an `AsynTask`, you can put the UI code in [onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29), wich is invoked on the UI thread with the result of `doInBackground`.

If you have intermediate results you can call [publishProgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) from `doInBackground`, this will trigger the invocation of [onProgressUpdate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) on the UI thread, where you can update the UI.

See [AsyncTask API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  for an example and more details on what must be done on which thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Reordering code (so GUI stuff would be done onPostExecute) worked. Also i had a problem with not getting to onPostExecute() but i had to change it to onPostExecute(Void result).

Now my code looks like this and works like a charm:

```
public class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

Context mContext;
LinearLayout mLl;

String tag = "DynamicFormXML";
XmlGuiForm theForm;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Handler progressHandler;

public DoInBackground(Context context, LinearLayout ll) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLl = ll;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    getFormData(params[0]);

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    DisplayForm();
}
```

I also added ScrollView and LinearLayout to my activity_main.xml so DisplayForm() looks like that (if you want to follow the example i mentioned before ):

```
private void DisplayForm() {
    try
    {           

        // walk thru our form elements and dynamically create them, leveraging our mini library of tools.
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<theForm.fields.size();i++) {
            if (theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getType().equals("text")) {
                theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj = new XmlGuiEditBox(mContext,(theForm.fields.elementAt(i).isRequired() ? "*" : "") + theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getLabel(),"");
                mLl.addView((View) theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj);
            }
    ...
```